# Can I create type alias to specify allocator for std containers?

Tags: rust

I want to define a type alias for a container from `std` using my custom allocator, e.g.

```
type MyBox<T> = Box<T, A=MyAlloc>;
```

however I'm told

```
error[E0229]: associated type bindings are not allowed here
  --> src/lib.rs:12:24
   |
12 | type MyBox<T> = Box<T, A=MyAlloc>;
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^ associated type not allowed here
```

Why is this not allowed, and is there some workaround (nightly is fine)?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0750f38d63ace7e44d6494e062538ae4)

Answer (score 8):

The default type always goes on the generic type *definition* for `A` (which is missing here -- you use `A` as a generic type without defining it) not on the place where the type is used.  This works:

```
type MyBox<T, A = MyAlloc> = Box<T, A>;
```

If you don't want the `A` parameter at all, then just specify your allocator type directly:

```
type MyBox<T> = Box<T, MyAlloc>;
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `A=`.

```
type MyBox<T> = Box<T, MyAlloc>;
```

This is all you need. Putting `A=` tries to define a constraint on an *associated type*, not a type parameter. That is, in a function signature, you might write

```
fn foobar<I>(iterator: I)
where I: Iterator<Item = u32>;
```

to constraint your function to only accept iterators whose element type is `u32`. That's because `Iterator::Item` is an *associated type* defined inside of the `impl` for `Iterator` (or, more precisely, the `impl` for its implementors), whereas the `A` in `Box<T, A>` is a simple type parameter, so you refer to it without its name.

Associated type constraints don't make sense in type aliases, which is why you're getting that error.